# SQL Proc 'Conversion failed' from varchar to int. Why the conversion?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, procedure

My question here would be... Why is it converting to int from varchar?  I'm not sure what it is trying to do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #myTestProcedure 
(
    @TransId VARCHAR(15)
) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(15);

WITH TestCTE (TransId, AdjRefTransId) AS
(
    SELECT TRANSID, ADJREFTRANSID
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE TRANSID = @TransId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT pet.TRANSID, pet.ADJREFTRANSID
    FROM dbo.MyTable AS pet
    JOIN TestCTE
        ON TestCTE.ADJREFTRANSID = pet.TRANSID
)

SELECT @Result = 
(
    SELECT MAX(MyResult)
    FROM dbo.MyOtherTable
    WHERE TRANSID = TestCTE.TRANSID
)        
FROM TestCTE
WHERE TestCTE.ADJREFTRANSID = ''

RETURN @Result
END

EXEC dbo.#myTestProcedure @TransId = 'MyTransId'
```

Error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure #myTestProcedure  0004C61A, Line 32
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MyResult' to data type int.
```

I can't see where it is trying to make this conversion.  Line 32 is a blank line.  No code there.

Comment: [The documentation spells it out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql): `RETURN [ integer_expression ]` <--- this can't be a string and, as Sean says, should not be used to output data. It should only be used for status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is your RETURN. Stored procedures return an integer to indicate the status of the execution, not return values. You would either need to Select @Result OR have @Result be an output parameter.