# How do i sum values after top 3 rows and group them under others

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table of participants of an apple picking completion. I have a table where all the participants are visible with the number of apples they have picked.

Now i want a table with that shows only the top 3 and the rest will be grouped under 'Others' and the total apples picked should appear against other

I have created the table which will have all the ids and the total apples collected

```
declare  @t table
    (
        id int,
        Apples_picked int
    )

    insert into @t
    select 1,10
    union
    select 2,12
    union
    select 3,3
    union
    select 4,15
    union
    select 5,23
```

Required output for the above table

```
ID  Name    Apples picked
5   winner  23
4   2nd     15
2   3rd     12
    Others  13
```

I am not sure how to add the everything after 3rd and sum it any guidance is much appreciated

Comment: Nice job on the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Apples_picked DESC) rn
    FROM @t
)
SELECT ID, 
    CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN 'Winner' WHEN 2 THEN '2nd' WHEN 3 THEN '3rd' END AS Name, 
    cte.Apples_picked
FROM cte 
WHERE rn <= 3
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, 'Others', SUM(apples_picked)
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 3
```

Returns:

```
ID      Name    Apples_picked
5       Winner  23
4       2nd     15
2       3rd     12
NULL    Others  13
```

Answer (score 1):

You want window function :

```
select max(case when Name <> 'Others' then id end) id,  Name, sum(Apples_picked) as [Apples picked]
from (select t.*, 
             dense_rank() over (order by Apples_picked desc) as seq
      from @t t
     ) t cross apply
     ( values (case seq when 1 then 'winner' when 2 then '2nd' when 3 then '3rd' else 'Others' end) 
     ) tt(Name)
where seq <= 33
group by Name
order by id desc;
```

If the `order by` is really important then you could change :

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Name = 'Others' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), [Apples picked] DESC
```

Here is a [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99e8cb98187e6b7242726d3c3e8942b6).

Comment: Take a closer look at your order by. It returns them in the correct order from the sample data by accident. Change the third place ID to 22 and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @SeanLange. . .  Yes order by should go with `Apples_picked`.

Comment: cross apply -- sometimes known as a lateral join.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using **CHOOSE()**

**Example**

```
;WITH cte AS (
    Select *
          ,[Name] = IsNull(choose(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Apples_picked DESC),'Winner','2nd','3rd'),'Others')
    FROM @t
)
Select ID = max(case when [Name]='Others' then null else ID end)
      ,[Name]
      ,Apples_picked=sum(Apples_picked)
 From cte
 Group By Name
 Order By case when [Name]='Others' then 1 else 0 end
         ,sum(Apples_picked) Desc
```

Returns

```
ID      Name    Apples_picked
5       Winner  23
4       2nd     15
2       3rd     12
NULL    Others  13
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that with two #Temp tables.  Select the top 3 into the first; select the sum of all the rows whose ID's are not in the first into the second; return the union of the two #Temp tables.

You could use CTE's rather than #Temp tables - the logic would be the same.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: He asked for "guidance", and this is "guidance".  If he'd posted his query and actual results along with the information he did post, I would have told him why it wasn't working.  Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370363/sql-proc-conversion-failed-from-varchar-to-int-why-the-conversion/54370427#54370427)

Comment: Fair point. But they put in the effort of providing consumable information I figure they deserved an answer.